# Counting days from two date fields, start counting from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: php, function, web, counter

I'm using a PHP function to count days between start date and end date for courses on a website. The function itself works flawless, however I'd like the counting to start from 1 as standard instead of 0.

My code looks like this

```
function dateDifference($start_date, $end_date) {
    // calulating the difference in timestamps 
    $diff = strtotime($start_date) - strtotime($end_date);
     
    // 1 day = 24 hours 
    // 6 * 60 * 60 = 86400 seconds
    return ceil(abs($diff / 86400));
}
```

I guess the answer to this question is pretty straight forward however I'm not that wandered in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "start from 1"?

Comment: Actually solved it myself, will post solution below. Thanks for taking time!

Answer (score 0):

After just some mins I managed to solve the mystery myself and now I feel pretty dumb since the solution really is super simple.. code below.

```
return ceil(abs($diff / 86400) +1);
```

So what I did was to add `+1` next to the calculation meaning the `$diff` array will add 1 day to however many days the calculation will count to.

Might help someone!